# Filling between two lines

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I've plotted two lines based on some scattered points, however, I now need to fill the area between the two lines.

```
counts_dataset = dataset('file','file.txt','Delimiter','\t');
x = counts_dataset.x;
y1 = counts_dataset.y1;
y2 = counts_dataset.y2;

line1 = line(x, y1,'Color', [.8 .8 .8])
line2 = line(x, y2,'Color', [.8 .8 .8])
```

I am now trying to fill in the region between the two lines as so:

```
fill([x fliplr(x)],[y2 fliplr(y1)],'c')
```

However, this gives me this plot:[image]

**disregard the scatter points**

Am I using the fill function incorrectly? How can I shade between the two lines?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350140/two-time-series-plots-and-shading-between-them-matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have some trouble with your data. The following code does exactly what you want:

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = sin(x) + 3;
y2 = sin(x);
fill([x fliplr(x)], [y2 fliplr(y1)], 'c')
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it