# Plot and fill area enclosed by n lines using Octave\Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, lines, fill, region

Lets suppose I have n curves, which together enclose some region. How to plot the curves and fill in the region they enclose using Octave/Matlab? Below is example for 3 curves (enclosed area is in black):
[image]

Comment: You might need to be more specific - even one curve could enclose arbitrarily many regions, and there is no universally applicable algorithm to locate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `fill`.

See the matlab documentation there:

http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/fill.html

Comment: That is  weird,  I thought that he meant how to find the intersections of the lines. But (+1) anyway, since I did not know about **fill**

Answer (score 0):

I used the *fill* and *flipr* functions in matlab to shade the area between two curves:

```
fill( [x fliplr(x)],  [upper fliplr(lower)], 'c', 'EdgeColor','none'), where x = (1:100)
```

and 'upper' and 'lower' are variables representing my two traces.

I received help from this post: [MATLAB, Filling in the area between two sets of data, lines in one figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245626/matlab-filling-in-the-area-between-two-sets-of-data-lines-in-one-figure)