# MATLAB Shading region between SEVERAL curves

Tags: matlab, plot, curve, region, shading

There are many questions already on this site for something similar:

[MATLAB, Filling in the area between two sets of data, lines in one figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245626/matlab-filling-in-the-area-between-two-sets-of-data-lines-in-one-figure#)

[MATLAB fill area between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910982/matlab-fill-area-between-lines)

However, all of the existing questions relate to two curves only. How do you fill a region bounded by *several* curves that overlap each other?

A crude example would be:

```
% Create sample data as column vectors.
x = [1 : 100]';
curve1 = x/10;
curve2 = log(x/2) + rand(length(x), 1) - 0.5;
curve3 = log(x) + rand(length(x), 1) + 0.5;
% Plot it.
plot(x, curve1, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on;
plot(x, curve2, 'b', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(x, curve3, 'k', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

For the shading:
The upper limit would be the black curve followed by the red line.

The lower limit would be the blue curve (briefly), then the red line, followed by the blue curve.

In my actual dataset I have 10 curves which require a similar thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this by creating a `min` and `max` vectors of the area you want to shade, and use `flipud` to shade the region with `fill`

```
min_data=min([curve1,curve2,curve3],[],2);
max_data=max([curve1,curve2,curve3],[],2);

fill([x;flipud(x)],[min_data;flipud(max_data)],'g')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
basevalue = min([curve1(:) ; curve2(:) ; curve3(:)]);
h = area([curve2 , curve1-curve2 , curve3-curve1],basevalue)
h(1).FaceColor = [1 1 1]; 
h(2).FaceColor = [0 0.5 0.5];  
h(3).FaceColor = [1 1 1];   
hold on
plot(x, curve1, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(x, curve2, 'b', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(x, curve3, 'k', 'LineWidth', 2);
ylim([ min([curve1(:) ; curve2(:) ; curve3(:)]);  max([curve1(:) ; curve2(:) ; curve3(:)])])
```

[image]

So you need to play with area in a way that is consistent with what you want...

Comment: Not quite! The area below the red line and the black curve on the right hand side of the plot should also be shaded. For the 'left' hand side of the plot, the area under the black curve and above the red line should also be shaded.

Comment: but that is the area that is shaded (below the red line and the black curve in the right hand side). your comment is not clear. please update the question with the area you want to shade (do it in MS paint or something).  also, try to understand what I did because the answer will be a variation of that,