# Fill area between two horizontal lines

Tags: matlab, plot, fill, area

I'm following the most voted answer of the question at the link below but I'm not getting anywhere.
[MATLAB, Filling in the area between two sets of data, lines in one figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245626/matlab-filling-in-the-area-between-two-sets-of-data-lines-in-one-figure)

I want fill the area between one horizontal line y=6 and other horizontal line y=9

```
x=ones(1,110)                  %#initialize x array
y1=6*(x);                      %#create first curve 
y2=9*(x);                      %#create second curve
X=[x,fliplr(x)];               %#create continuous x value array for
Y=[y1,fliplr(y2)];             %#create y values for out and
fill(X,Y,'b');                 %#plot filled area
```

Simply it's not working! Any idea why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be simplified:

```
area([1 110],[9 9],6)    % plot a line between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), then fill down to a baseline (6)
ylim([0 10])             % scale y axis to fit
```

For straight lines, you only need two points, not 110.

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there.

X should contain the index of the x-points (1:110) and not `ones(110)`.

```
X=[1:110,fliplr(1:110)];
```

gives

[image]