# Matlab plotting different shadings between lines of standard deviations

Tags: matlab, plot, std

I have a problem with the plots I'm using for an article.
After a lot of search on the web, I still haven't found a solution, so I'll try to describe my problem as clear as possible:

I'm plotting two parameters and have added their standard deviations with the fill-function. Because I don't want to use colors, I want to use different shadings for the space between the standard deviations.
Until now the problem I have, is that I'm unable to specify, that the shading is consistent between the standard deviation of one parameter as you can see in the picture. I would like to have is one type of shading between the doted lines and another type of shading between the solid lines.

```
z = linspace(1,101,101)';

f=figure;
set(f,'Units', 'normalized', 'outerposition', [0 0 1 1]);

fill( [z' fliplr(z')],  [Parameter1_plus_std' fliplr(Parameter1_minus_std')], 'k');
alpha(0.4);
hold on
plot(normal,Parameter1_mean,'k','LineWidth',2);

fill( [z' fliplr(z')],  [Parameter2_plus_std' fliplr(Parameter2_minus_std')], 'k--');
alpha(0.2);
hold on
plot(Parameter2_mean,'k--','LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

In the picture, you can see that the darker shading is between the doted and the solid line, where it should be between the doted line!

I would be thankful for any thoughts on this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB, Filling in the area between two sets of data, lines in one figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245626/matlab-filling-in-the-area-between-two-sets-of-data-lines-in-one-figure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you used `alpha` to make all the lines of the plot visible. The problem is, that the two half-transparent fillings get added and therefore are darker where they overlap. So you cannot use `alpha` for what you want to achieve. But with the third argument of `fill` you can specify a solid color of the filling. To use different shades of grey, use the RGB-definition with a three-element-vector like `[0.5 0.5 0.5]`.

Now you can generate the two fillings with different shades of grey without borders using `'LineStyle','none'` or `'EdgeColor','none'`. After just plot all the lines on top.

*Here is the code:*

```
z = linspace(1,101,101)';

% generate some data to plot
normal = z;
Parameter1_mean = 9.225e-06.*z.^3-0.00159.*z.^2+0.07392.*z-0.4292;
Parameter1_plus_std = Parameter1_mean+0.08;
Parameter1_minus_std = Parameter1_mean-0.11;
Parameter2_mean = 9.225e-06.*z.^3-0.00156.*z.^2+0.07332.*z-0.4232;
Parameter2_plus_std = Parameter2_mean+0.11;
Parameter2_minus_std = Parameter2_mean-0.08;

% create figure
figure('Units', 'normalized', 'outerposition', [0 0 1 1]);
hold on

% plot the two solid fillings without border
fill([z',fliplr(z')], [Parameter1_plus_std',fliplr(Parameter1_minus_std')], 0.8*[1 1 1], 'EdgeColor','none');
fill([z',fliplr(z')], [Parameter2_plus_std',fliplr(Parameter2_minus_std')], 0.6*[1 1 1], 'EdgeColor','none');

% plot all the lines
plot(normal,Parameter1_mean,'k-','LineWidth',2);
plot(Parameter1_plus_std,'k-')
plot(Parameter1_minus_std,'k-')
plot(Parameter2_mean,'k--','LineWidth',2);
plot(Parameter2_plus_std,'k--')
plot(Parameter2_minus_std,'k--')

% some tweaking
xlim([min(z),max(z)])
```

*This is the result:*

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use transparency. You can't achive what you want with transparency, you have to use solid colors.

For instance:

```
figure('Units', 'normalized', 'outerposition', [0 0 1 1]);
hold on

fill( [z' fliplr(z')],  [Parameter1_plus_std' fliplr(Parameter1_minus_std')], 0.4*[1 1 1], 'Linestyle', '-');
plot(normal,Parameter1_mean,'k-','LineWidth',2);

fill( [z' fliplr(z')],  [Parameter2_plus_std' fliplr(Parameter2_minus_std')], 0.2*[1 1 1], 'Linestyle', '--');
plot(Parameter2_mean,'k--','LineWidth',2);
```

Note that I can't execute that code here since I don't have the data, this is a blind shot and it may contain small errors to correct.

Best,

Comment: Using this, I could only see one std, while the other one was hidden behind it. But that the use of transparent colors was the problem, was a good hint :)