# MATLAB: Filling the area between multiple lines

Tags: matlab, plot, fill

A book I'm reading contains the following diagram.

[image: ORSS with False Alarm rate on x-axis and Hit Rate on y-axis]

I'm looking to replicate as closely as possible the following diagram in MATLAB. I managed to recreate the lines, but am having trouble filling the colours in.

```
possible_colours = {'r','g','b','c','m','y','w','k','r'};

H = [0.01:0.01:0.99];

colour_counter = 0;

for ii = -0.8:0.2:0.8
    colour_counter = colour_counter + 1;
    colour_now = possible_colours{colour_counter};
    ORSS = ones(1,size(H,2))*ii;
    F = (H .* (1-ORSS)) ./ ((1-2.*H) .* ORSS + 1);
    hold on    
    plot(F,H)
    fill(F,H,colour_now);    
end
```

With `fill(F,H,colour_now)` taken out the code perfectly recreates the required lines. However, the fill isn't correct.

This [heavily upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561835/1205197) by @Doresoom seems relevant, but it's a bit different because in that example the x-values are held constant, while in my case it's the y-values that are held constant. Also, in that case there is only a pair lines, whereas I have lots of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a solution:

```
%possible_colours = {'r','g','b','c','m','y','w','k','r'};
possible_colours = {'r','g','b','c','r','k','w','y','m'};

H = [0.01:0.01:0.99];

figure; hold on
fill([0 1 1],[0 0 1],colorlowerhalf)
fill([0 1 0],[0 1 1],colorupperhalf)

colour_counter = 0;

for ii = -0.8:0.2:0
    colour_counter = colour_counter + 1;
    colour_now = possible_colours{colour_counter};
    ORSS = ones(1,size(H,2))*ii;
    F = (H .* (1-ORSS)) ./ ((1-2.*H) .* ORSS + 1);
    hold on    
    plot(F,H)
    fill(F,H,colour_now);    
end

for ii = 0.8:-0.2:0
    colour_counter = colour_counter + 1;
    colour_now = possible_colours{colour_counter};
    ORSS = ones(1,size(H,2))*ii;
    F = (H .* (1-ORSS)) ./ ((1-2.*H) .* ORSS + 1);
    hold on    
    plot(F,H)
    fill(F,H,colour_now);    
end
```

It permits to avoid the overlap of the filled areas.

But there still is some problem with the definition of the areas to fill.

For that you need to redefine `H`:

```
H = [0:0.01:1];
```

Comment: That works brilliantly! Do you know if there's some easy way to fill in the top-left and bottom-right sections, i.e. the sections in purple and dark blue in the original diagram?