# Generating a curve around the point on a scatter plot

Tags: matlab, plot, curve-fitting, area, best-fit-curve

I am generating a scatter plot containing data from multiple sources, as displayed below.

[image: Scatter plot]

I would like to be able to generate a curve surrounding an arbitrary query point and passing through points on scatter plot. Final goal is to calculate the area between the lines on the plot.

I have implemented solution using finding points with [`knnsearch`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) in a circular fashion and then applying [`hampel`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hampel.html) filter to eliminate noise. In the example below, I have selected a point right about in the middle of the blue-shaded area. As you can see, the result is far from perfect, and I need more precision.

[image: Not so perfect result]

I am looking for something similar to [`boundary`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) function, but to work from the inside of the point cloud, not from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

> Final goal is to calculate the area between the lines on the plot.

I would do it differently. Just take any two lines of the plot, calculate the area under the curves with some kind of numerical approximation (for example [trapezoidal numerical integration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html)), then subtract the areas and obtain the area between the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use curves. I had to take much different approach for the rest of the solution, but this got me started.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to idea in Trilarion's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40892843/388664), I was able to come up with the better solution.

Note that I use notation for YZ plane instead of XY (to keep consistent with robot coordinate system).

## Solution

#### Generate curves for each set of scatter data

```
% Scatter data is in iy and iz vectors.
curve = fit(iy, iz, 'smoothingspline', 'SmoothingParam', 0.5);
% Remove outliers.
fdata = feval(curve, iy);
I = abs(fdata - iz) > 0.5 * std(iz);
outliers = excludedata(iy, iz, 'indices', I);
% Final curve without outliers.
curve = fit(iy, iz, 'smoothingspline', 'Exclude', outliers, 'SmoothingParam', 0.5);
```

#### Plot curves and scatter data

```
% Color maps generated by MATLAB's colormap function.
h_curve = plot(curve);
set(h_curve, 'Color', color_map_light(i,:));    
scatter(iy, iz, '.', 'MarkerFaceColor', color_map(i,:))
```

#### Let user provide an input by selecting points

User selects one point as a query point and two points for limits along Y axis. This is because some curves come close, but never intersect.

```
[cs_position.y, cs_position.z] = ginput(1);
[cs_area_limits, ~] = ginput(2);

if cs_area_limits(1) > cs_area_limits(2)
  cs_area_limits = flipud(cs_area_limits);
end

plot_cross_section(cs_position);
```

#### Finally calculate and plot surface area

This section uses [fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561835/388664) by Doresoom.

```
function [ ] = plot_cross_section(query_point)
%PLOT_CROSS_SECTION Calculates and plots cross-section area.
%   query_point  Query point.

  % Find values on query point's Y on each of the curves.
  z_values = cellfun(@(x, y) feval(x, y),...
    curves, num2cell(ones(size(curves)) * query_point.y))

  % Find which curves are right above and below the query point.
  id_top = find(z_values >= query_point.z, 1, 'first')
  id_bottom = find(z_values < query_point.z, 1, 'last')

  if isempty(id_top) || isempty(id_bottom)      
    return
  end

  % Generate points along curves on the range over Y.
  y_range = cs_area_limits(1):0.1:cs_area_limits(2);
  z_top = feval(curves{id_top}, y_range).';
  z_bottom = feval(curves{id_bottom}, y_range).';

  % Plot area.
  Y = [ y_range, fliplr(y_range) ];
  Z = [ z_top, fliplr(z_bottom) ];
  fill(Y, Z, 'b', 'LineStyle', 'none')
  alpha 0.5
  hold on

  % Calculate area and show to user.
  cs_area = polyarea(Y, Z);
  area_string = sprintf('%.2f mm^2', cs_area);
  text(0, -3, area_string, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
end
```

## Result

[image: Result image]