# How can I fill an area below a 3D graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, fill

I created the following 3d plot in MATLAB using the function `plot3`:

[image]

Now, I want to get a hatched area below the "2d sub-graphs" (i.e. below the blue and red curves). Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to realize that.

I would appreciate it very much if somebody had an idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using the function [`fill3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html) and referencing [this answer for the 2D case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6252647/52738) to see how you have to add points on the ends of your data vectors to "close" your filled polygons. Although creating a pattern (i.e. hatching) is difficult if not impossible, an alternative is to simply adjust the alpha transparency of the filled patch. Here's a simple example for just one patch:

```
x = 1:10;
y = rand(1, 10);
hFill = fill3(zeros(1, 12), x([1 1:end end]), [0 y 0], 'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
grid on
```

And here's the plot this makes:

[image]

You can also create multiple patches in one call to `fill3`. Here's an example with 4 sets of data:

```
nPoints = 10;  % Number of data points
nPlots = 4;    % Number of curves
data = rand(nPoints, nPlots);  % Sample data, one curve per column

% Create data matrices:
[X, Y] = meshgrid(0:(nPlots-1), [1 1:nPoints nPoints]);
Z = [zeros(1, nPlots); data; zeros(1, nPlots)];
patchColor = [0 0.4470 0.7410];  % RGB color for patch edge and face

% Plot patches:
hFill = fill3(X, Y, Z, patchColor, 'LineWidth', 1, 'EdgeColor', patchColor, ...
              'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
set(gca, 'YDir', 'reverse', 'YLim', [1 nPoints]);
grid on
```

And here's the plot this makes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps me a lot!