# Shading of area between two lines not working correctly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, fill

I am trying to plot the shaded uncertainty (upper and lower bounds) along a line. I tried using the `fill` function but it is including an area larger than I want. I have an upper error (black), lower error (green), and actual data line (red), like so:

[image]

How do I get the area between the green and black lines? I tried the following:

```
fill([date fliplr(date)], [data_Upper fliplr(data_Lower)], 'r');
```

But the fill function covers both line areas all the way to the bottom of the plot:

[image]

How do I fix this to only shade the area between the lower and upper error line bounds?

Comment: With this data: `date = 1:5;` `data_Upper = date;` `data_Lower = date-1;`, everything seems to work. Can you a give a [mcve]?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6245626/2586922) help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have used wrong lower bounds data.

Here is a simple MATLAB example for that, you could modify it to include your lines,

```
x =[1 2 3 4 5];%Both lines share same x value
y1=x+1;%Equation for first line
y2=2*x;%Equation for second line
% plot the line edges
hold on 
plot(x, y1, 'LineWidth', 1);
plot(x, y2, 'LineWidth', 1);
% plot the shaded area
fill([x fliplr(x)], [y2 fliplr(y1)], 'r');
```

The outcome of running this is

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your data is arranged in column vectors (i.e. N-by-1) instead of row vectors (i.e. 1-by-N). Your code above assumes row vectors. Try using [`flipud`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) and [vertical concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) instead:

```
fill([date; flipud(date)], [data_Upper; flipud(data_Lower)], 'r');
```

To elaborate, when you pass an N-by-M matrix to most plotting routines, like [`fill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html), it will plot one object per column. In this case, I believe you are creating N-by-2 matrices and passing them to `fill`, when you should be passing either 1-by-2*N or 2*N-by-1 vectors for a single filled object.

Comment: Nowadays, `fliplr` and `flipud` are deprecated, in favor of just plain `flip`. Using  that function it is less likely that the flip direction is wrong.