# shading confidence interval in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, confidence-interval

I am trying to shade the area between the confidence limits and for that I am using the [ciplot function](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13103-plot-confidence-intervals?focused=5083489&tab=function). The x, lower and upper values are all 300*1 vectors. This is my code.

```
a_99_CI_lower=0.5877*c1+1.5462;
a_99_CI_upper=0.7511*c1+2.5205;
plot(c1,a_99_CI_lower,'k');
hold on
plot(c1,a_99_CI_upper,'k');
ciplot(a_99_CI_lower',a_99_CI_upper,c1)
```

And the output I get is:
[image]
Why does only a part of the bounds is shaded. I want the whole area between the two lines be shaded. There are no NaN values in the vectors. So, what am I doing wrong here?

I tried the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245626/matlab-filling-in-the-area-between-two-sets-of-data-lines-in-one-figure)
and then with the below code all I get is the two black  lines

```
XCI=[c1,fliplr(c1)];                
YCI=[a_99_CI_lower,fliplr(a_99_CI_upper)];              
fill(XCI,YCI,'g');
```

Comment: Always provide a [mcve]

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I remember one version had a bug that caused this type of errors when rendering patches. Try changing the renderer: `set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters');`